# How to align words backwards in CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a list with a few items. I am using Flexbox and because I want the list in the middle of the screen I use justify-content:center however that puts everything to the center even some things I don't want to, like the headers. Then when I try to use flex-direction:row-reverse it simply won't do what I expect.
Remember that I want the text to be in the center of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Why not make a div which you align in the center, and then inside that div use text-align: right ?

Comment: nothing to do with flex I guess ... simple text-alignment with some padding on the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments suggest, you can simply make use of `text-align`

```css
.center-div {
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.center-text {
    text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="center-div">
  <div class="center-text">
    Example <br>
    Example second <br>
    Example third <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lfj7gy92/1/)

Comment: we don't center a div with text-align .. your first wrapper is useless

Comment: Beautiful. It's much better when a proper answer is put together than a simple comment of the style "use that kbye".